# Unexpectedly borrowed value does not live long enough after method call

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to iterate over a deepening finite state space while maintaining a set of seen states. The following function is incomplete, but defined enough to demonstrate the problem I'm having.

```
fn get_possible_final_results(&self, mut seen: BTreeSet<ValveState>) -> Vec<u16> {
    if self.is_done() {
        return vec![self.result];
    }
    let mut successors = self.get_successors();
    let mut results = Vec::new();
    while !successors.is_empty() {
        let successor = successors.pop().unwrap();
        if seen.contains(&successor) {
            continue;
        }
        let new_successors = successor.get_successors();
        successors.extend(new_successors);
        seen.insert(successor);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Here's the signature of get_successors. Returned `ValveState`s don't reference `self` (or at least they shouldn't).
`fn get_successors(&self) -> Vec<ValveState>`

The compiler implies that successor is borrowed beyond the length of a method call at some point, but I don't understand how or why.

```
error[E0597]: `successor` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:78:34
   |
67 |     fn get_possible_final_results(&self, mut seen: BTreeSet<ValveState>) -> Vec<u16> {
   |                                                    -------- has type `BTreeSet<ValveState<'2>>`
...
78 |             let new_successors = successor.get_successors();
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
79 |             successors.extend(new_successors);
80 |             seen.insert(successor);
   |             ---------------------- argument requires that `successor` is borrowed for `'2`
81 |         }
   |         - `successor` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Shouldn't the call the `get_successors` only borrow `successor` for the duration of that method call? Am I misunderstanding the problem?

I've tried introducing various lifetimes (which I'm still getting a handle on) to no avail. I've also tried searching for this error elsewhere, and I'm sure it's out there, but I've been unable to find an explanation that addresses this specific situation.

As you can probably tell, I'm still getting used to Rust. Any help is appreciated, even if you have to explain it like I'm five years old. Thanks!

---

Here's more information about `ValveState` and how it's constructed in `get_successors`:

```
struct ValveState<'a> {
    network: &'a ValveNetwork<'a>,
    player_position: &'a str,
    open_valves: BTreeSet<&'a Valve<'a>>,
    steps_left: u16,
    result: u16
}
```

An example of a `ValveState` being constructed in `get_successors`:

```
let new_state = ValveState {
    network: self.network,
    player_position: self.player_position,
    open_valves: self.open_valves.clone(),
    steps_left: self.steps_left - 1,
    result: self.result+ self.get_step_result()
};
successors.push(new_state);
return successors;
```

Comment: What is the definition of `ValveState`, and how are they being constructed in `get_successors`? Seems that it is generic over a lifetime, and due to [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) the `ValveStates` returned by `get_successors` have the same lifetime as `&self`.

Comment: @EvilTak updated question with more info. Is it something to do with the fact that multiple `ValveState`s are sharing references to things like `ValveNetwork` and `&str` names?

Comment: But then, clearly, `get_successors` borrows the `network`, `player_position` and `open_valves` for the returned `ValveState` from `self`—and so `self` must remain borrowed until that returned `ValveState` is dropped.

Comment: Actually, I take that back.  What is the definition of `successor`?  If you're just copying references into `ValveState` and preserving their lifetimes then you should have something like `impl<'a> Successor<'a> { fn get_successors(&self) -> ValveState<'a> { ... } }`.  That is, relate the lifetime parameter of the returned `ValveState` to the lifetime parameter of the successor.  Without that, the lifetime is assumed to be that of `&self`.

Comment: (Written before your second comment) @eggyal I was under the impression that giving things like `self.network` (`&ValveNetwork`) and `player_position` (`&str`) are just providing new states with the same immutable reference to the same data, rather than borrowing the reference itself. Is this not the case? And also, shouldn't the `open_valves.clone()` turn that into owned data, moving it into the new state?

Comment: @eggyal your second comment identified the issue. Gonna have to study up on the difference between that and lifetime declarations in functions. Accepted as the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@eggyal's second comment clued me in on the issue. I had previously only tried defining an `'a` lifetime in `ValveState` function declarations, rather than as in `impl<'a> ValveState<'a>`. I clearly need to solidify my understanding of what the differences between these things are, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I hadn't looked closely and failed to spot that `successor` was itself a `ValveState`.  In this case you can actually have `fn get_successors(&self) -> Self` since `Self` preserves the lifetime parameter whereas `-> ValveState` is shorthand for `-> ValveState<'_>` which means "use the elided lifetime from the function parameters" (ie that of the borrow `&self`).